# Enable HTTPS in Lighttpd

Tags: https, openssl, lighttpd

I would like to enable HTTPS in Lighttpd. I have a "key" file (created using openssl), along with the certificate and intermediate certificates generated by the SSL provider but I'm not sure how these files are usedin Lighttpd. It seems like the config file is expecting a file in "pem" format.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I will also include the step for generating the keystore and CSR file.

**CSR Generation**

On the terminal, type (and enter your details).

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

**HTTPS Configuration**

1) You need to merge your keystore with the certificate returned by the issuer. This can be done in a text editor but I'd recommend doing it on the command line.

```
cat server.key domain_com.crt > domain.pem
```

2) To enable HTTPS in Lighttpd, open **lighttpd.conf** and enter the following

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    ssl.engine = "enable"
    ssl.pemfile = "[path to domain.pem]"
    ssl.ca-file = "[path to CA bundle containing root and intermediate certs]"
}
```

3) Make sure the server has the relevant permissions to read the certificate files.

4) Restart the Lighttpd service.

Comment: If you pass the same filename for both `--keyout` and `--out` parameters, then openssl will merge both key and certificate into one file for you. So that you can skip your step 1) then.
Alternatively, you can still use two separate files for certificate and private key, using `ssl.pemfile` and `ssl.privkey` variables of `lighttpd.conf` correspondingly.